What can be done to improve the UX of stack exchange?
Does anyone have improvements they would suggest to the UX of this site or Stack Exchange sites in general? I would like to see some of the hierarchy of tags for example so that some tags are nested under other tags in order to be able to get to topics I am most interested in.

See questions with feature-requests tagged for some past suggestions and ideas.
